# Getting C2660 parameter error when redirecting cout (stuck in Visual Studio 6)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to port a couple of methods into a pipeline on a totally different hardware environment where I don't have a lot of flexibility. I am forced to use Visual Studio 6 and a cygwin shell.

To help debug while getting things set up, I want to redirect the output of a "dump()" method, which prints to cout, to a file. I can't override or extend the dump method at the moment so I am trying the old trick

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

std::ofstream out("out.txt");
std::cout.rdbuf(out.rdbuf());
```

Which runs just fine in my regular Eclipse environment. But here I am getting

```
error C2660: 'rdbuf' : function does not take 1 parameters
```

I am guessing that 1998-era C++ may not have allowed this override? Is this correct? Can anyone suggest an option that might work?

Comment: Highlight `rdbuf`, press F1, read documentation.  You can also go look in the header and see what the declaration looks like.

Comment: "The MSDN collection does not exist". I get some luck with a cursor hover. It shows a void method only but I can't tell if this means there would be no others (i.e. it's not overloaded).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243825(v=vs.60).aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266867(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Most so-called C++ compilers aren't fully standard conforming, but MSVC 6 is so old and broken that it really doesn't deserve to be called a C++ compiler. UPGRADE! Also, realize that our answers to your questions may not work with VC6, as what it accepts is too far away from standard C++.